# How to create a cascading query finding parent/child rows from table

Tags: oracle

I hoping someone can help with what seems like a simple query, but seems to be harder than I anticipated.
I'm looking to find the parent rows for the child row based on the corresponding ID.

```
TABLE1
------------------------------
ID  LEVEL   VALUE   PARENTID
------------------------------
1   COUNTRY UK      NULL
2   COUNTRY FRA     NULL
3   CITY    LONDON  1
4   CITY    PARIS   2
5   RIVER   SEINE   4
6   RIVER   THAMES  3
```

.

```
SELECT VALUE FROM TABLE1 WHERE VALUE = 'THAMES'
...ID = PARENTID
...ETC
;
```

So for example with the above table I can pass in 'THAMES' and it will find the parent and parent's parent and so on, until it gets to a NULL value. for example:

```
THAMES
LONDON
UK
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Sorry thought it was there, so if you put THEMES, you get THEMES > LONDON > UK.

Answer (score 2):

```
with table1 as 
(
  select 1 as id, 'COUNTRY' as lvl, 'UK' as value, null as parentid from dual union all
  select 2 as id, 'COUNTRY' as lvl, 'FRA' as value, null as parentid from dual union all
  select 3 as id, 'CITY' as lvl, 'LONDON' as value, 1 as parentid from dual union all
  select 4 as id, 'CITY' as lvl, 'PARIS' as value, 2 as parentid from dual union all
  select 5 as id, 'RIVER' as lvl, 'SEINE' as value, 4 as parentid from dual union all
  select 6 as id, 'RIVER' as lvl, 'THAMES' as value, 3 as parentid from dual
)
select value from table1
connect by id = prior parentid
start with value = 'THAMES';

VALUE 
------
THAMES
LONDON
UK
```

Answer (score 1):

What I did to answer this was the following (see the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=365211b7b88ce4038a59e6ab931d10e9)):

Create and populate the table:

```
CREATE TABLE tab
(
  t_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  t_lev VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
  value VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
  parent_id INT
);

INSERT INTO tab VALUES (1, 'COUNTRY', 'UK', NULL);
INSERT INTO tab VALUES (2, 'COUNTRY', 'FRA', NULL);
INSERT INTO tab VALUES (3, 'CITY', 'LONDON', 1);
INSERT INTO tab VALUES (4, 'CITY', 'PARIS', 2);
INSERT INTO tab VALUES (5, 'RIVER', 'SEINE', 4);
INSERT INTO tab VALUES (6, 'RIVER', 'THAMES', 3);
```

And then run this query (I've left in some fields which aren't necessary - just to show my (the) thinking):

```
WITH t1 (t_id, parent_id, lvl, root_id, path, value) AS
(
  SELECT 
    t.t_id, t.parent_id, 1 AS lvl, t.t_id AS root_id, 
    TO_CHAR(t.t_id) AS path, t.value
  FROM tab t
  WHERE t.parent_id IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    t2.t_id, t2.parent_id, lvl + 1, t1.root_id, 
    t1.path || '-> ' || t2.t_id AS path, t1.value || '-> ' || t2.value AS pth
  FROM tab t2, t1
  WHERE t2.parent_id = t1.t_id
)
SELECT * FROM t1;
```

Result:

```
T_ID    PARENT_ID   LVL     ROOT_ID     PATH        VALUE
   1         NULL     1           1     1           UK
   2         NULL     1           2     2           FRA
   3            1     2           1     1-> 3       UK-> LONDON
   4            2     2           2     2-> 4       FRA-> PARIS
   5            4     3           2     2-> 4-> 5   FRA-> PARIS-> SEINE
   6            3     3           1     1-> 3-> 6   UK-> LONDON-> THAMES
```

With thanks to the ever-excellent Tim Hall and his [oracle-base site](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/recursive-subquery-factoring-11gr2) - a wonder to behold!

To pick out the 'THAMES', just add

```
SELECT * FROM t1
WHERE INSTR(value, 'THAMES') != 0;
```

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0a28bae0251f1f606f69cb061582a9f2).